# Ignoring special characters when processing txt using python

Tags: python, special-characters

My python program processes txt file but it stops once it meets some bad characters.

I managed to ignore some of them by

```
while line.endswith(u'\u0085') or line.endswith(u'\u001E') or line.endswith(u'\u001D') or line.endswith(u'\u001C') or line.endswith(u'\u001A') or line.endswith(u'\u2028'):
```

But well, this solution doesn't work if there is still other bad character in the document.

So, I just want to ignore ALL special characters that don't show up in notepad++.

Maybe another solution would be to delete all such special characters that don't show up in notepad++

Either solution will be great.

Comment: Please define special characters better. The reason they are not showing up in notepad++ is likely because your font does not have symbols for them. That does not make them really special though…

Comment: `endswith()` takes a tuple too: `line.endswith((u'\u0085', u'\u001E', u'\u001D', u'\u001C', u'\u001A', u'\u2028'))`.. Define 'characters that don't show in notepad++, that's not much to go by.

Comment: @poke For example if I open txt with notepad++, then I can't see u0085 even if it is there. I needed sublime text to see that there's u0085. I used just standard encoding for notepad++ like UTF-8 (to see non-English characters).

Comment: @poke Or still putting in different way, I might just mean special characters that force python program to stop. For example, my program stopped when there is u0085.